# Regular expression - Match on least amount of text from start

Tags: regex

I'm now sure how best to word the question but I believe an example will make it totally clear.

Current Regular Expresion

```
^(?:weight\s?)?(\d{1,2})(?:k|kg)$
```

That says match on string starting with "weight" (optional) followed by 1 or 2 digits followed by a "k" or a "kg" at the end.

Is there a way to write the final part of expression without the OR (k|kg)?
I would prefer if it was something like

```
(?:kg)~
```

Where ~ says match this text or text that is a subset of this i.e. "k". Another example would be

```
(?:mmhg)~
```

Which would match "m", "mm", "mmh" or "mmhg" at the end.

**Obviously I totally made up the "~" notation**

**UPDATE**

I am generating these expressions so i could definitely do something like take the text and split into individual chars and build a list of "|" like below but I'd rather not.

```
(?:m|mm|mmh|mmhg)
```

Comment: Should the pattern be built dynamically? What is the programming language then?

Comment: I am building dynamically so I could definitely just split the units "kg" or "mmhg" or whatever it is in to multiple "|"s but i didn't want to

Comment: There is no way other than using your language means to build the pattern as shown by anubhava below.

Comment: I'm not a `.NET\C#` coder, but what I'd be tempted to do, in perl, would be to create a variable for my `$ValidUnits` and maintain that variable. That way, the capture expression would only have to be `^(?:weight\s?)?(\d{1,2})(?:$ValidUnits)$` it keeps the code clean and simplify the task of maintaining the list up to date, were I to evaluate it at more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^(?:weight\s?)?(\d{1,2})kg?$
```

Where `kg?` will match `k` or `kg`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nnXBuf/1)

For the second part you can use:

```
\bm(?:m(?:hg?)?)?\b
```

This will match `m` or `mm` or `mmh` or `mmhg`

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/nnXBuf/2)

Comment: I want one way of writing any unit "mmhg", "kg" or "foo"

Comment: What is your regex language?

Comment: I am building dynamically in .NET\C# so i could definitely write (?:k|kg) or (?:m|mm|mmh|mmhg) but I would have preferred not too

Comment: Using 2nd pattern I've shown you can build it dynamically by iterating through each character from 2nd position onwards. For `foo` it would be `\bf(?:oo?)?\b` and for `abcde` it will be `\ba(?:b(?:c(?:de?)?)?)?\b`

Comment: Is \bf(?:oo?)?\b any better than \bf|fo|foo\b?

Comment: Yes definitely better because we are avoiding repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, since it doesn't really seem to be a unit you're looking for, is something like:

```
^(?:weight\s?)?(\d{1,2})(?:\w+?)$
```

That would match anything, made of letters, after your 1 or 2 digit. It wouldn't allow you to compare it against valid values, though. So I would advise against that. Though if you were to eventualy capture also the second parenthesis, `(\w+?)$`, you could easily do a test of that second value post capture and treat the data of the first parenthesis based on the second parenthesis value.